# acces weight attributes from .txt file in networkx

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I am building a model using networkx and want to read in the weight values from a txt file in the following format: `a b {'weight': 0.8}`

How can I then access the weight attribute from edge a->b in my code?

I can now only access all the edges at once with the following code:

```
from pylab import *
import networkx as nx

g = nx.read_edgelist('model_weights.txt', delimiter = ' ', 
create_using = nx.DiGraph())

print G.get_edge_data(data=True)
```

Comment: Is opening the file and parsing the text a good enough solution for you?

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Comment: I can post an answer if you run into any issues

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am first trying to get the rest of the code to work without using networkx, then I will have a look at the parsing.